# How to correctly sync the master and branches on a forked repo from github

Tags: git, github

I have forked a repo on github. Then I created a new branch for a feature I'm adding (lets call the branch 'my-new-feature'). I've worked on my branch a bit and pushed all my work back to github (the 'my-new-feature' branch). Now, the user has made numerous changes to the upstream.

Questions:

1) What is the correct way to sync my branch (as well as my forked master) with the upstream?

- do i need to first switch to (checkout) the forked master or should I just fetch upstream (into the current branch)?

```
git checkout master
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
```

- as I understand, the above updates the forked master on my local machine. I then need to push it to github, right?

`git push origin`

2) Is it possible to sync my forked master and all my branches all at once, or do I have to do it one by one? i.e. after I've updated the forked master, do I need to repeat with all my branches:

```
git checkout my-new-feature
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
git push origin my-new-feature
```

or am I being dumb and there's a much easier way to do this?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing any of the work of keeping `origin` and `upstream` synchronized on your machine, you could ask *github* to pull down the changes from upstream for you. I mean, that is sort of the point of a fork. The only reason to do this on your machine is if you need "manual" fork management.

If you *do* decide to do "manual" fork management, there is no reason to fetch and merge `feature` from `upstream` — because, by definition, `upstream` doesn't have it. So, the first thing you said is the usual thing, if you don't want to do it all on github. Fetch `upstream`, merge into `master`, push to `origin` (or not, if no one is sharing it with you there is no rush after all), and now switch back to `feature` and proceed as if there were no `upstream`.

Comment: Thank you, so there is no way to have github pull down the changes automatically (e.g. once every 24h)? I have to do it manually each time right?

If there's no reason to fetch and merge `feature` from `upstream` how do I keep `feature` up-to-date with changes in `upstream` ?

Comment: The question makes no sense. `feature` has no relation to "changes in `upstream`". What you want to do is keep it up-to-date with changes in `origin`, and the answer is: the same as you always do, whatever that is: keep merging `master` into `feature` or whatever.

Comment: And no, I am not aware of any automatic fork updating; indeed, that sounds like a question I once asked here. :)

Comment: Thank you! So I just need to do `git checkout feature` and `git merge master` or `git merge origin/master`.

if I didn't update my fork's master, can i just (update my feature branch with) merge from upstream `git checkout feature` and `git merge upstream/master`?

Comment: I think so but I don't quite see why you'd do that. However, perhaps my life is too sheltered. :)